# How can I automate two buttons with dud href using selenium ? Both contains a function name & arguments in href

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html code for both buttons are given below:

```
<td>
<a href="javascript:abcMy(2310);" class="btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa">View</a>
</td>


<td>
<a href="javascript:abcMy(2330);" class="btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa">View</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info as: 1. What have you tried? Show code. 2. What worked for you? 3. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to click on botton1, It will navigate to some other page--> Come back to same page--> Click on button 2. It is working fine with Xpath command given                                                                    
 WebElement element10 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa']" ));                                                                                      but how can I click on button2

Comment: For us to help you, you need to provide the relevant HTML DOM & point us exactly where you are stuck. Share the URL if it is a public URL.

Comment: It is not public.HTML DOM also not available. There is a report page with two buttons to view reports. Both buttons share same class, id, even href of buttons are same except function argument.

Comment: Since they belong to same class which I used in xpath, working fine with button1. My problem is that I am not able to click on button2.

Comment: Code for function is                                                                       
   function abcMy(a) {
 $('#dvViewCaseHistory').load("CaseMaster/viewsilecaseSummary",{ id:a});
};

Comment: `WebElement element10 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa']" ));` is working because Selenium is referring to the very first element detected by this xpath. So that essentially means this xpath is not unique. You must have unique xpath for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath , and identify them uniquely based on their index.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these below mentioned **xpath**

Use indexing after complete your `xpath`

**Note:-** Indexing start from `1`

Suppose if you want to click on `second view link button`, then use below xpath.

```
//a[text()='View'][2]
```

> OR

```
//a[@class='btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa'][text()='View'][2]
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute along with `text` method with `<a>` tag.

> OR

If you want to click on `first view link button`, then use below xpath.

```
//a[text()='View'][1]
```

> OR

```
//a[@class='btn btn-lawa btn-primary btn-primary-lawa'][text()='View'][1]
```

Comment: Dipti, have you try my answer? Is it work for you as you expected?

Comment: Working fine with button 1 only. I am not able to click on button 2

Answer (score 0):

The element is inside the table. you can also try this way...

1. Inspect the xpath of of table. For Ex:

> .//*[@id='ID']/div[2]/table/tbody/

2. Move to the row of the table. So if your row no. is 2 then your xpath will be

> ".//*[@id='ID']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]"

3. Now Move to the cell of that row of the table. If your table cell is 4 then your xpath will be

> ".//*[@id='ID']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]"

4. Inside [td], here is your element. Finally move to your element and your xpath will be

> ".//*[@id='ID']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver3.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href='javascript:abcMy(2330);']")).click();
```

selects second button. You can directly select them by using cssSelector as above.